# Pre-Processor directives in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, c-preprocessor

I seem to be having trouble with preprocessor directives in C#.  I've created a Visual Studio 2008 C# win forms app.  I add this:

```
#if (DEBUG)
            textBox1.Text = "in debug mode";
#else
            textBox1.Text = "in release mode";
#endif
```

And when I run in debug I see the expected "in debug mode".  However when I switch to Release, compile, and run the .exe, I still see the "in debug mode" text.  In my project properties I have Define `DEBUG` constant checked.  I even get the correct color-coded syntax for the code above.  What gives?

Comment: perhaps you are running the wrong .exe?

Comment: BTW, Pre-Processor directives should be avoided where possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any chance you have DEBUG defined for both Debug and Release configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a "#define DEBUG" line ? That sets DEBUG to true always.