# Getting Command Timeout while debugging Stored Procedure with VS 2008

Tags: .net, debugging, stored-procedures, timeout

I am trying to debug my application that calls some stored procedure.

I don't have any problem with debugging the procedures.

The problem is, when I am debugging, the default command timeout for connections is 30 seconds, so when I am debugging, the execution of that thread will stop and is throw one exception that indicates "Timeout".

I need to increase the command timeout or exists some way, that 'knows' that I am debugging and it extends the timeout automatically?

Apreciate your help,
thanks

Comment: Are you running a tests? What type of testsoftware are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio to debug my Stored Procedures.
This situation is not used in tests. Is just for me, to understand some local variables generated from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
SqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0; //0 is for unlimited
```

Or you can use pre-processor directives just for debugging purpose see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha(v=vs.71).aspx and here [Pre-Processor directives in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637061/pre-processor-directives-in-c-sharp) are some details.

Answer (score 0):

By using SQL Server management studio you should be able to increase the timeout. 
But I think that by default, on a dev installation it is already very high ( a few hours if im correct).